# Markers aren't working properly when I use them on a component

Tags: leaflet, vue.js, vue-component

So I start using leaflet on my site, and I manage to make a search in which with the name of my items, I could show them. the problem is that I need to display information on click, but my markers aren't clickable.

here is my component:

```
<template>
    <div id="mapid" style="width: 600px; height: 400px"></div>
</template>


<script>
    var swal = require('sweetalert');
    var config = require('../../config.js');
    var Vue = require('vue');
    name: 'mapOrganization',
        data: function(){
            return {
                L : {},
            }
        },
ready: function(){
var L = require('../../lib/leaflet/leaflet.js')
        L.Icon.Default.imagePath = '../../lib/leaflet/images';
        this.initMap();
}
methods: {
initMap: function(organizations) {

            var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
            L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpandmbXliNDBjZWd2M2x6bDk3c2ZtOTkifQ._QA7i5Mpkd_m30IGElHziw', {
                maxZoom: 18,
                attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
                '<a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
                'Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
                id: 'mapbox.streets'
            }).addTo(mymap);
            L.marker([51.5, -0.09]).addTo(mymap).bindPopup("<b>Hello world!</b><br />I am a popup.").openPopup();
            L.circle([51.508, -0.11], 500, {
                color: 'red',
                fillColor: '#f03',
                fillOpacity: 0.5
            }).addTo(mymap).bindPopup("I am a circle.");
            L.polygon([
                [51.509, -0.08],
                [51.503, -0.06],
                [51.51, -0.047]
                ]).addTo(mymap).bindPopup("I am a polygon.");
            var popup = L.popup();
            function onMapClick(e) {
                popup
                .setLatLng(e.latlng)
                .setContent("dasd" + e.latlng.toString())
                .openOn(mymap);
            }
            mymap.on('click', onMapClick);
           }
         }
```

I have try with the Option {clickable: true}, still not working. I'm using the simple example leaflet give on start.

Comment: Which version of Leaflet do you use? Would you be able to reproduce your issue on Plunker / JSBin / JSFiddle? Not reproducible with plain Leaflet 1.0.0-rc.3: https://jsfiddle.net/3v7hd2vx/81/

Comment: The version is Leaflet 1.0.0-rc3, I'm trying to reproduce it on JSFiddle, But i'm not quite sure how to do a vue component in there, so Imma keep trying. 
by the way, If I paste the code in my Index it works, the problem is if I use it on my component. [as you can see,I can't click on the markers](http://i.imgur.com/WrEru56.png).

Comment: @ghybs I manage to fix it, I thought this would work var L = require('../../lib/leaflet/leaflet.js'), but maybe I download some old version or I don't know. but I add this <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.0-rc.3/dist/leaflet.js"></script> in my index file and it start working.